# AngularJS 2.0 binding & event handling

Tags: angularjs

I am playing around with AngularJS 2.0

My very simple scenario consists of a select box that is bound to a property of component attribute, like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="zeitraum" [value]="zeitraum" (change)="calculate()">
<option>....</option>
</select>
```

The component class looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent
{
    constructor
    (
        public zeitraum: number = 10,
        public result: number = 0
    )
    {

    }

    public calculate()
    {
        this.result = this.zeitraum * 5;
    }
}
```

So, I have a select box with a couple of options and I want the following behaviour: when a new option is selected, call the calculate() method which simply multiplies 'zeitraum' by 5 and then sets the value of 'result' which is then displayed on the page.

```
<h1>Result: {{result}}</h1>
```

The problem is as follows: The calculate method is called but it uses the **OLD** value of 'zeitraum' (that is, the value **before** a new option was selected).

I wonder which event to use here. I tried a workaround by using (mouseleave) and (mousemove) events and that seemed to work but it's a really dirty hack so there should be a more elegant solution.

Either I am using the wrong event or I got something else wrong with my Angular code.

Has anybody a suggestion? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="zeitraum" (change)="calculate($event.target.value)">
    <option>....</option>
</select>

public calculate(zeitraum)
{
    this.result = zeitraum * 5;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it has no effect on the result.